# How magento 2.1 can show the image?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

[image]

How magento 2.1 can show the image? Which file or code do that? I am using Magento-CE-2.1.8_sample_data.

Comment: We need more information what image you need to load product image or simple image media or skin images?

Comment: I mean product's image. How can Magento show that in Magento-CE-2.1.8_sample_data?

Answer (score 0):

The image will be place in the `pub/media` folder. Also you need is get the path of the folder. Try this:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

protected $_filesystem;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $_filesystem,
)
{
    $this->_filesystem = $_filesystem;
}
```

And get the path of the image:

```
$image_path=$this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath()."catalog/product/i/image.jpg";
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

In your template you can try following code:

```
<?php
    $image = 'product_small_image';
    $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($product, $image)->getUrl();
 ?>
```

For $image there is a lot of type of images you can find an list in this file

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml

You can define other type in your theme

Comment: I find this code: (in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml):
<a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl()?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
           <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>

what different this code to your code? Do they work the sample way?

Comment: It’s the same my code you can use it in any template and the other code is used only in list.phtml hope that helped you

Comment: are there any blogs or videos that I can learn to make some simple extension in magento 2?